# Floating object changes shape because of noise texture

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

This is a sub-question of something I'm trying to make. An earlier post with the complete story turned out to be too unclear and contained too many questions. My apologies for that! I will now split the earlier post into several parts. Do I have to open a new thread for each question or can I post the other questions here?

Within geometry nodes I try to make a cube as a whole move along on the same noise of two layers. However, the cube changes shape because the vertices of the cube are controlled by the noise field of the "layer noise" frame.

[image]

Node tree:

[image]

How can I make sure the cube keeps its shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to input the same vector in the noise for all vertices in the cube.

[image: single vector noise input]

But if you dont want to duplicate your noise nodes, you can transform a single vertex in the desired position and transfer it to all of the cube:

[image: single vertex offset to cube]

Here a Mesh line with a single vertex captures the noise result, which is then transferred to the cube by selecting the attribute in the index 0 (the only vertex).

If you want to use the cube's center as input for the noise, you can use the Attribute Statisctic Node to get the mean position and then you connect it to the start position of the Mesh Line Node:

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot! This is a nice setting for overcoming the noice in the object. For the next question I need to use instances so I will go further with that.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to somehow reduce the position of your cube to a single position.

Then only this one position would be evaluated.

This would be easy if you would instantiate your cube at one single existing point.

But since you don't do that, you could go the other way, and reduce the evaluated positions of the node `Noise Texture` to one point.

And you do that with the node `Attribute Statistics`.

This will give you the midpoint of the evaluated positions, and you can use this directly as offset.

[image]

*(Since you didn't share your blend file and I didn't rebuild your nodes 1:1, I reproduced this from memory, so please bear with me if this doesn't work right away and give me some feedback)*

Comment: Tnx a lot for your reaction. For the next part I need to work with the cube as intances so pick that option for now. Only using the attribute statistic didn't work for me. The settings of Hulifier below are great.